# for what $\nu$ does Riemann-Liouville differintegral of digamma function $\psi(z)$ exist?

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function, fractional-calculus

For what values of $\nu$ does the Riemann-Liouville differintegral $_{-\infty}D_{z}^\nu$ of the digamma function $\psi(z)=\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}$ exist, with $c=-\infty$? All I've got so far is that the derivatives exist, i.e. the differintegrals when $\mathrm{Re}(\nu)>0
$.

Many thanks for any help with this!

Comment: Can you show your work?

Comment: The proof that the derivatives exist is a bit long to include here! :-) But I've now sorted this out: the definition of fractional derivatives assumes the existence of fractional integrals with $-1<\mathrm{Re}(\nu)<0$, so we must be able to extend to $\mathrm{Re}(\nu)>-1$, which was all I needed.

Comment: Have you by any chance seen [the paper by Moll and Espinosa](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10652460310001600573)? That might give you something to start with... still, the poles of the polygamma functions in the left half-plane has me skeptical that the beasts are well-defined for noninteger $\nu$ and lower limit $-\infty$...